# I'm in Spain, Job in Spain, yet Jobs speaks French to me

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

*Tagging this "bug" although it's a very minor issue, if it is one at all.*

An oddity in the Careers display - the country name in one of these ads is in French:

[image]

I'm located in Spain, and definitely have no browser settings implying French as a language, so this must be coming from the backend.

Maybe the person who posted the job (maybe with a fr-FR language setting in their browser) started entering their native "España" and accepted the automatic suggestion that came up without checking it.

Either way, it seems that place name didn't get normalized, which may or may not be the intended behaviour.

Comment: Funny because, on one hand "Barcelona" is not French (should be "Barcelone"), but "Espagne" is. I'd go for the automatic suggestion.

Comment: Don't see bug, no free-hand red circle.

Comment: @rene, Am I doing it right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gLMD.jpg

Comment: @Bhargav that's a fairly Spain-shaped freehand circle (when turning it by 90°) so that'll do.

Comment: @Tunaki: I suspect their geonames database is horrible with regard to localized names. Careers had my city with the wrong name for ages without any way for me to rectify it (seems better now, though).

Comment: Funny, your screenshot speeks English to me...

Comment: Well, those ads always want me to move all over Europe. Last week they thought I should move to Germany, this week it seems to be Finland. And they think I should work with Javascript and Matlab. Funny, as I haven't got a clue about those technologies. It is blatantly obvious that SO just spam advertise to everyone and their mother, to be able to say "your advert reached x million developers!"

Comment: Nevermind, refreshed the page and now I'm moving to Switzerland! Or Denmark, to work with HTML.

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue lately, although I'm in the UK I keep getting a German ad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rKbC.png

Comment: @Lundin don't be so negative, man. Take it as a sign!!!

Comment: but, but.... what's wrong with french?!

Comment: I don't particularly care about the adverts, I ignore them just fine. But SO staff always seems very concerned about them, as we can see from the recent user survey. "Did you feel that the advert was relevant?" Well, have you even seen the adverts yourself, Sherlock...